# Why does my code spit out the wrong text?

Tags: python-3.x

> I wanted to write a code that takes two variables, compares which one has a higher value and then spits out the one with the higher value.
> The code is:

```
champ1 = input("first champ: ")
champ2 = input("second champ: ")
Ashe = 590
Jhin = 444
champs = [Ashe, Jhin]
if champ1 > champ2:
    print(champ1)
else:
    print(champ2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Debugging questions require a [mre], but you're missing the input, expected output, and actual output, plus `champs` is unused. See [ask] if you want more tips.

Answer (score 0):

To compare numbers turn them into Integers.

```
champ1 = int(input("first champ: "))
champ2 = int(input("second champ: "))
if champ1 > champ2:
    print(champ1)
else:
    print(champ2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran your code, it is working just fine

```
champ1 =   int(int(input("first champ: "))
champ2 =  int(input("second champ: "))
Ashe = 590
Jhin = 444
champs = [Ashe, Jhin]

if champ1 > champ2:
    print(champ1)
else:
    print(champ2)
```

Note
The variable named **champs** was defined but was never used in your code,
only the user entered inputs is what is being compared.

Comment: Wrong. When you input a number it stores it as a string. In this case the user wants to compare numbers so you have to convert it to int.

Comment: @Chen, Not totally wrong but best practice to cast or validate inputs. thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you requested for user input, proceeded to not use it then assign values?

Also, you are comparing string values(the supposed user input) and not the contents of your champs list.

See here:

```py
#initiate list and take input
champs = []
Ashe = int(raw_input('Number?'))
Jhin = int(raw_input('Number?'))

#append to list
champs.append(Ashe)
champs.append(Jhin)

#compare and print
if champs[0] > champs[1]:
    print(champs[0])
else:
    print(champs[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat more pythonic approach:

```py
champions = [input("first champ: "), input("second champ: ")]
print(max(map(int, champions)))
```

```
first champ: 50
second champ: 900
900
```